# Placing nodes which vary in length harmoniously

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, very thick]
  \def\r{3}
  \foreach \a/\n in {-2/{p-2}, -1/{p-1}, 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4}
     \node[anchor=base] (\a) at (90+36*\a:\r) {$\circ$};
  \node (-3) at (90+36*-3:\r) {};
  \node (5) at (90+36*5:\r) {};
  \foreach \a/\name [remember=\a as \lasta (initially -3)] 
                in {-2/{p-3}, -1/{p-2}, 0/{p-1}, 1/0, 2/1, 3/2, 4/3, 5/4}
    {
    \draw[->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] 
        (\lasta) 
        arc[radius=\r, start angle=90+36*(\lasta), end angle=90+36*(\a)]
        (\a);
    \node at (90+36*\lasta+18:\r+0.5) {$\alpha_{\name}$};
    }
  \foreach \a in { 1, ..., 14 } 
    {
    \node at (90+36*5+5*\a:\r) {$\cdot$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following picture
[image]

I find the placing of the labels on the arrows rather disturbing. I tried quite a few things but they always end up in rather unsymmetric positions.

> Is there a way to get them to behave well?

Of course, the correct meaning of *well* here is open to interpretation, but I'd like at least the alphas to show up at more consistent distances from the arrows, for example.

PS. I'm putting the labels by hand and not as nodes along the arc because that way they seem to be better, but I expect this is a bad choice...

Comment: If you could say how you'd like them to look, people could help.... I mean, they look basically OK to me.

Comment: The centers are symetrical to the circle, but the labels themselves vary in width and orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Does this look any more esthetically pleasing?

[image: offset labels]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, very thick]
  \def\r{3}
  \foreach \a/\n in {-2/{p-2}, -1/{p-1}, 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4}
     \node[anchor=base] (\a) at (90+36*\a:\r) {$\circ$};
  \node (-3) at (90+36*-3:\r) {};
  \node (5) at (90+36*5:\r) {};
  \foreach \a/\name [remember=\a as \lasta (initially -3)] 
                in {-2/{p-3}, -1/{p-2}, 0/{p-1}, 1/0, 2/1, 3/2, 4/3, 5/4}
    {
    \draw[->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] 
        (\lasta) 
        arc[radius=\r, start angle=90+36*(\lasta), end angle=90+36*(\a)]
        (\a);
    \pgfextra{\settowidth{\tempwidth}{$\alpha_{\name}$}
       \pgfmathparse{0.5+0.005\tempwidth*cos(90+36*\lasta+18)}% fudge factor 0.005
       \global\let\temp=\pgfmathresult}
     \node at (90+36*\lasta+18:\r+\temp) {$\alpha_{\name}$};
    }
  \foreach \a in { 1, ..., 14 } 
    {
    \node at (90+36*5+5*\a:\r) {$\cdot$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here the alphas are symmetrical (subscripts are ignored).

[image: rlap subscripts]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, very thick]
  \def\r{3}
  \foreach \a/\n in {-2/{p-2}, -1/{p-1}, 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4}
     \node[anchor=base] (\a) at (90+36*\a:\r) {$\circ$};
  \node (-3) at (90+36*-3:\r) {};
  \node (5) at (90+36*5:\r) {};
  \foreach \a/\name [remember=\a as \lasta (initially -3)] 
                in {-2/{p-3}, -1/{p-2}, 0/{p-1}, 1/0, 2/1, 3/2, 4/3, 5/4}
    {
    \draw[->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] 
        (\lasta) 
        arc[radius=\r, start angle=90+36*(\lasta), end angle=90+36*(\a)]
        (\a);
     \node at (90+36*\lasta+18:\r+0.5) {$\alpha_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle\name$}}$};
    }
  \foreach \a in { 1, ..., 14 } 
    {
    \node at (90+36*5+5*\a:\r) {$\cdot$};
    }
  \node at (3.5,0) {\phantom{$alpha_{p-3}$}};% push right border
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would set the anchor for the point.

```
\documentclass[border=25pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\aesub[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\scriptsize$#1$}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, very thick]
  \def\r{3}
  \foreach \a/\n in {-2/{p-2}, -1/{p-1}, 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4}
     \node[anchor=base] (\a) at (90+36*\a:\r) {$\circ$};
  \node (-3) at (90+36*-3:\r) {};
  \node (5) at (90+36*5:\r) {};
  \foreach \a/\name [remember=\a as \lasta (initially -3)] 
                in {-2/{p-3}, -1/{p-2}, 0/{p-1}, 1/0, 2/1, 3/2, 4/3, 5/4}
    {
    \draw[->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] 
        (\lasta) 
        arc[radius=\r, start angle=90+36*(\lasta), end angle=90+36*(\a)]
        (\a);
    %% to avoid writing the same thing multiple times
    \pgfmathsetmacro\aeangle{90+36*\lasta+18}
    %% to see the node
    \node[circle,inner sep=0.5pt,fill] at (\aeangle:\r+0.5) {};
    \node[anchor=(\aeangle+180),outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] at (\aeangle:\r+0.5) {$\alpha_{\aesub{\name}}$};
    %% old style for comparison purposes
    %% \node[anchor=(\aeangle+180),outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] at (\aeangle:\r+0.5) {$\alpha_{\name}$};
    }
  \foreach \a in { 1, ..., 14 } 
    {
    \node at (90+36*5+5*\a:\r) {$\cdot$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've made the nodes visible so you can better see the placement.  Just comment out that line.  Also, I've added a command that makes the subscripts into boxes of zero width, natural height, and zero depth:  the natural height is left there so the subscript gets placed correctly (ie., not too heigh).  This has the slightly undesirable result that the bounding box isn't quite set.  But otherwise, this solution sets the anchor on the $\alpha$ and not the entire $\alpha_{...}$.  If you're find with setting on the entire label name, then don't use the `\aesub` macro.